# Make class type a Dictionary key (Equatable, Hashable)

Tags: ios, swift

Say I have a class named `LivingCreature`
And other classes that inherit from it:

- `Human`
- `Dog`
- `Alien`

This is what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
let valueForLivingCreature = Dictionary<Alien, String>
```

And access it like so:

```
let alienValue = livingCreatureForValue[Alien]
```

But this means the class should conform to `Equatable` and `Hashable`, but the class itself, not the class instance.
I've tried various ways of accomplishing this, but no luck.

As a compromise I've came up with is:

```
typealias IndexingValue = Int
class LivingCreature {
     static var indexingValue: IndexingValue = 0 
}
```

And then I can use the class as a key like so:

```
 let livingCreatureForValue = Dictionary<IndexingValue, String>
```

Access:

```
let alienValue = livingCreatureForValue[Alien.indexingValue]
```

But, this way the IndexingValue should be set per class, by hand.
I would like to make a hash from the class itself like so:

```
class LivingCreature {
    static var indexingValue: IndexingValue {
        return NSStringFromClass(self).hash
    }
}
```

This is not possible because `self` is not accessible is static var.

My question is, is there a better way of addressing this kind of issue?

**Edit:**

@Paulw11 Asked me why not make LivingCreature confirm to Equatable and Hashable,
The reason is I would not be able to access the value by the class type reference.
 I would have to alloc an instance every time:

```
let alienValue = livingCreatureForValue[Alien()]
```

I do not want to call "Alien()" every time for finding a value.
And the component that uses it, doesn't care about the livingCreature instance, only about the class type.

Comment: Why don't you make your `LivingCreature` conform to `Equatable` and `Hashable` and override the relevant functions?

Comment: Because then I would have to alloc LivingCreature every time, for getting I'ts value. That is the reason I would like to use the class  type, and not a class instance.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. If your class conforms to Hashable and Equatable then all subclasses conform to those protocols and you can use instances of those classes as dictionary keys.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to use class objects as your dictionary keys? That sounds like you are going about things the wrong way. If you want a string that describes the class why not implement a class function that returns a string and override that function in the subclasses. No need for a dictionary

Comment: @Paulw11 I've edited my question. And about doing something wrong, there are manny different options of designing code, for my purpose this functionality is something I would like to have. And that is the reason I'm asking a question, to see if there is a better practice to do what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: You can use the approach you had with the `indexingValue` but just use a static func instead of a static var  in your `LivingCreature` class - `static func creatureType() -> Int {
        return NSStringFromClass(self).hash
    }` then you can say `LivingCreature.creatureType()` or `Human.creatureType()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume your are trying something like:

```
let valueForLivingCreature = Dictionary<LivingCreature.Type, String>
```

and:

```
let alienValue = valueForLivingCreature[Alien.self]
```

Then you can use `ObjectIdentifier`:

```
class LivingCreature {
    class var classIdentifier: ObjectIdentifier {
        return ObjectIdentifier(self)
    }
    //...
}

class Human: LivingCreature {
    //...
}

class Dog: LivingCreature {
    //...
}

class Alien: LivingCreature {
    //...
}

let valueForLivingCreature: Dictionary<ObjectIdentifier, String> = [
    Human.classIdentifier: String(Human),
    Dog.classIdentifier: String(Dog),
    Alien.classIdentifier: String(Alien),
]

let alienValue = valueForLivingCreature[Alien.classIdentifier] //->"Alien"
```

But in most use cases when you want to use meta-class as a dictionary key, you can find another way around:

```
class LivingCreature {
    class var classValue: String {
        return String(self)
    }
    //...
}

class Human: LivingCreature {
    //...
    //Override `classValue` if needed.
}

class Dog: LivingCreature {
    //...
}

class Alien: LivingCreature {
    //...
}

let alienValue = Alien.classValue //->"Alien"
```

Comment: ObjectIdentifier just what I was looking for, thank you so much